# Token Count Token length

Tags: java, token

Hey everybody i'm new to java and I'm doing a bonus assignment for my intro to java class and i was wondering if some one could help guide me for the bonus questions: i just need a starting point! Thanks for any help!

This is the original Requirements for the assignment :

1) A constructor that accepts a single argument, a String for the name of the input file to process.  DONE 
2) A function named processFile(), that accepts no arguments, and throws an IOException. This function must read the input file's contents and count the number of times each token (word) exists in the file. A member variable HashMap is a good class to use for this.
3) A getFileName() function, no arguments, returns a String that contains the input file name.
4) A getTokenCount() function, no arguments, returns an int that is the total number of tokens (words) in the input file.
5) A getTokenCount() function, that accepts a String argument, and returns the number of times that token (word) appears in the input file.
6) A getTokensHavingCount() function that accepts an int argument (the count), and returns an ArrayList of Strings, where those Strings are the tokens that appear exactly "count" times in the input file.
7) A getTokensHavingLength() function that accepts an int argument (the length), and returns an ArrayListof Strings, where those Strings are the tokens in theinput file that have that exact length.
8) A getAverageOfCounts() function, no arguments, returns the average of the token counts.

As this is the code i have so far,

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment4 {
// Your member variables go here
    private String filename;
    private int wordcount; // ?
    private Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>(); // <Key,Value>


    public Assignment4(final String fileName) {
        this.filename = fileName;
    }

    public void processFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            file = null;

            String text = "";
            String line = reader.readLine();    
            while (line != null) { 
                text = text + line + " ";
                line = reader.readLine();   
            }

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
            wordcount = st.countTokens();
        }

    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return filename; 
    }

    public int getTokenCount() {
        return freq.size;  
    }

    public int getTokenCount(final String key) {
        return freq.get(key);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTokensHavingCount(final int count) {

        ArrayList<String> wordCount = new ArrayList<String>();

        Set<String> set = freq.keySet();
        for (String word : set) {
            int noOfTimes = freq.get(word);
            if (noOfTimes == count)
                freq.add(word);
        }
        return wordCount;
     }

     public ArrayList<String> getTokensHavingLength(final int length) {

         ArrayList<String> wordlength = new ArrayList<String>();

         Set<String> set = freq.keySet();
         for (String word : set) {
             if (word.length() == length)
                 wordlength.add(word);
         }   

         return wordlength;    
     }

     public int getCountOfTokensHavingCount(final int count) {
         return getTokensHavingCount(count).size(); 
     }

     public int getCountOfTokensHavingLength(final int length) {
         return getTokenHavingLength(count).size; 
     }

     public double getAverageOfCounts() {

         ArrayList<String> wordlength = new ArrayList<String>();
         double sum = 0.0d;
         Set<String> set = freq.keySet();
         for (String word : set) {
             sum += freq.get(word);
         } 
         return sum / (double) freq.size();
     }  
}
```

Bonus #1: Add a function named getCountOfTokensHavingCount(), that accepts an int argument (count), and returns the number of tokens which appear in the input file exactly "count" times.

Bonus #2: Add a function named getCountOfTokensHavingLength(), that accepts an int argument (length), and returns the number of tokens which appear in the input file having exactly "length" characters in the token.

Comment: "Add a function..." What are we adding a function to? It is impossible to answer without knowing this, e.g. you reference an "input file" and "tokens", but don't give any details as to how these are currently obtained.

Comment: Please give us the full code you already have. You seem to be working with files. Without the full code of all classes you use, nobody can help you.

Comment: Hint for #1: `Map<Token, Integer>`.

Comment: Making edits to the original code and will upload thanks guys!

Comment: @AndyTurner update the question with the full code

Comment: @RobertMcHardy updated the question with the full code

Comment: Whenever you iterate through a map's key set and call `Map.get` for the iteration variable, you should instead iterate the entry set. This gives you back the key and value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things.

- Your function `processFile` doesn't do what it should do. Your task is to count how often each word appears in the text. Idea: Read the file word by word (take a look at `java.util.Scanner`); if the word isn't already in your `HashMap` you add the word as the Key and the number 1 as the value; if the word is already in your `HashMap` you increase the value by one.
- Why do you set `file = null` in `processFile`? You should properly close the `BufferedReader` instead by using a `finally`. Java can actually do that for you automatically: `try(FileReader freader = new FileReader(file); BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(freader)) { // Your actual code }`.
- Your `getTokenCount` function should return `freq.size()` (you call a function, not an attribute!).
- Also please use **always** curly braces after an if or a loop, regardless of there is only one thing you do or a huge code block.

Comment: Your try-with-resources doesn't quite clean up correctly: if an exception is thrown in construction of the `BufferedReader`, the `FileReader` is not closed. It should be in a separate initialisation statement: `try (A a = new A(); B b = new B(a)) {`